# ¿Por que mi función no hace nada?

Tags: c++, funciones, estructuras

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int promedio(struct alumno a, int x);

struct alumno{
    
    char nombre[50];
    int calificaciones[3];
    
};

int main(){
    
    alumno a;
    int tam=3;
    float f;
    
    cout<<"Introduce tu nombre: "<<endl;
    cin>> a.nombre;
    
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        
        cout<<"Calificacion "<<i+1<<endl;
        cin>> a.calificaciones[i];
        
        
    }
    
     promedio(a, tam);
    
    
    return 0;
}

int promedio(struct alumno a, int x){
    
    
    for(int b; b<3; b++){
        
        cout<<"Calificacion: "<<b+1<<endl;
        cout<<a.calificaciones[b];
        
    }
```

}

Hola, estoy iniciando en esto de las estructuras en c++ y estoy haciendo este programa, al ejecutarlo, la función "promedio" no hace nada, no se si sea problema de los parámetros o que este pasando, espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.
Según yo, la función esta siendo llamada correctamente, por lo que no se cual sea el problema

Comment: En la función promedio en el `for` no debería ir la variable `b` asi `for(int b=0; ....)`???

Comment: Por favor, explicá cuál es el comportamiento esperado. Te recomiendo leer: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Christian tenias razón, no me había dado cuenta de eso, gracias

Comment: @D4RIO Gracias, lo tomaré en cuenta para futuras preguntas

Comment: Lo probé, y en mi caso funciona. Creo que al código de `promedio()` le faltan las últimas líneas (seguramente un `return 0;` y una llave `}`